# How do I send a string or any other value from another WPF Window to another?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

This was easier in Windows Forms. So I have a tabbed program. And I added a feature to rename a tab. When they rename a tab it directs you to a new WPF Window and they set the name there, if they click 'Enter' the dialog result would be true and in the the main window the code is

```
TabRename ren = new TabRename();
ren.txtNewN.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header);
if (ren.ShowDialog() == true)
  {
     tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header = ren.txtNewN.Text;
  }
```

the problem there is that it returns the first value which is set by the line

```
ren.txtNewN.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header);
```

and if you get the value by

```
tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header = ren.txtNewN.Text;
```

it would return the default one...

Comment: Why `ren.txtNewN.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header);`? You can just use `ren.txtNewN.Text= tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by the code you have posted, but assuming your `TabRename` code looks something like this I'd say it should work fine.

```
public class TabRename()
{
    public string NewName 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return txtNewN.Text; 
        } 
        set
        {
            txtNewN.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then just say this

```
TabRename ren = new TabRename();
ren.NewName = tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header;
if (ren.ShowDialog())
{
    tabI[tabM.SelectedIndex - 1].Header = ren.NewName;
}
```